# Setting Up PTR to correct "Forged hostname" error

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-bounces, ptr-record

Our e-mails mostly get through fine, but here's an error I haven't seen before.

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.7.1 ... Forged hostname for 66.132.221.45 >which resolves as www.medialabinc.net but www.medialabinc.net does not resolve back to >66.132.221.45. Check your DNS A and PTR records.

We have PTR records for our two server's IPs (the IPs that send mail, 66.132.221.45 and 66.132.221.46). medialabinc.net resolves to 66.132.220.196, which is the IP of the load-balancer. So, we have:

> PTR
>
> 66.132.221.45 => medialabinc.net
>
> 66.132.221.46 => medialabinc.net
>
> A
>
> medialabinc.net => 66.132.220.196

Is there anything I can do here, if wayne.edu is insisting that 66.132.221.45 => medialabinc.net => 66.132.221.45?

Answer (score 0):

The target mailserver rejects this message because your outbound IP's don't pass [FcRDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) checks. your outbound mail IP shouldn't use a PTR which points to a completely different IP ( www.medialabinc.net -> 66.132.220.196).  you could give each outbound IP a unique PTR which resolves back to the IP and you're all set.

Example:

- 66.132.221.45 **PTR** outbound1.medialabinc.net
- outbound1.medialabinc.net **A** 66.132.221.45
- 66.132.221.46 **PTR** outbound2.medialabinc.net
- outbound2.medialabinc.net **A** 66.132.221.46